# Listview in the texformfield

Tags: forms, flutter, grouped-list

i have a listview (use the package groupedlistview) and i would like put in the texformfield, with a possibility to select an item. Please it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about dropdown button. So you can check [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).